# fork/pipe/dup2 issue: child process never exits

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe, dup2

I want to write a small program that prints out a long list which can be *paged* in the terminal through `more` (or `less`) so that the list can be examined from head to toe...

The program:

- `fork`'s off a child process in which the `more` program is executed
- In the parent process, the list is printed
- There is a `pipe` set up between parent/child so that the list printed to `stdout` by the parent is sent to the `more` program's `stdin`

code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pager, status;
    int pipes[2];

    pipe(pipes);

    pager = fork();

    if (pager == 0) { // child

        dup2(pipes[0], 0);
        close(pipes[1]);
        char *args[] = {"more", NULL}; 
        execvp(args[0], args);

    } else { // parent

        dup2(pipes[1], 1);

        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
            printf("Hello World! %d\n", x);
        }  

        close(pipes[0]);
        close(pipes[1]);

        wait(&status);
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

I have this working for the most part:

- The long list of "Hello World!..." messages are printed on the terminal clipped by a `--More--` so I know the basic pipe setup is working.
- If I press `[q]` before the entire list finishes printing (quit the `more` process) the programs (parent/child) exit as expected

The only problem I am having is that if I keep pressing `[space]` or `[return]` (which advances the output given by `more`) and reach the end of my list (the 500th "Hello World!..." message) then the terminal just hangs.  Pressing `[q]` is unresponsive (I have to  `[ctrl+c]` to get out).

The parent process is stuck on `wait`.  *The `more` process is not exiting even though I have closed both pipes in the parent*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are closing `pipe[0]` which is not the descriptor you are writing to the child. You did a `dup2(pipes[1], 1)` so in order to tell the child that the pipe has ended you must close the one you are writing to.

```
close(1);
```

Of course you'd have to restore the original output if you intend to continue your process using stdout, as this would be closed now.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately.  Killing the pager results in the parent process exiting almost immediately since there is nothing to wait on.  No output is printed at all with this change.

Comment: Did you try with SIGTERM?

Comment: Yeah, I just reproduced it.

Comment: I updated my answer, as I found the problem. Works now for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Note that I am closing pipe[1] as well as pipe[0] in the parent.  Closing pipe[1] as well as fd(1) is necessary in order to achieve correct behavior.  Closing fd(1) only or pipe[1] only has the original problem.

Comment: Yeah, you must close those descriptors in order to not run out of desc riptors, but they have no other functional consequence. Closing `1` is the one that your child is listening to, so this is the one that triggers the exit.